# How do select row with max(column value) group by another column in SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by, sql-order-by

i dont't know how to select row with max column value group by another column. I have T-SQL

```
CREATE PROC GET_USER
AS
BEGIN
SELECT  A.USER_ID, B.START_DATE , D.START_DATE, A.FULL_NAME,A.COST_CENTER,
F.DEPARTMENT_NAME,G.BU_NAME
FROM USERS A INNER JOIN USER_PERSON B ON A.USER_ID=B.USER_ID
INNER JOIN TYPE_PERSON C ON C.TYPE_PERSON_ID = B.TYPE_PERSON_ID
INNER JOIN USER_TRANSACTION D ON D.USER_ID = A.USER_ID
INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONS E ON E.TRANSACTION_ID = D.TRANSACTION_ID
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT F ON F.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID
INNER JOIN BUS_UNIT G ON G.BU_ID = D.BU_ID
INNER JOIN BRANCH H ON H.BRANCH_ID = D.BRANCH_ID
INNER JOIN POSITION J ON J.POSITION_ID = D.POSITION_ID
WHERE A.FLAG = 'TRUE' 
END
```

[image]
the result will select max(B.START_DATE) and max(D.START_DATE) and Group by USER_ID

[image]

Comment: What result do you want when (for a particular USER_ID) MAX(B.START_DATE) is in one row, but MAX(D.START_DATE) is in another row?

Comment: I think B.START_DATE in a table B , D.START_DATE in table D, not same , I should group by USER_ID,then group by B.START_DATE and D.START_DATE and select  max them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT  T.USER_ID ,
        MAX(T.START_DATE) AS [Max First Start Date] ,
        MAX(T.[Second Start Date]) AS [Max Second Start Date]
FROM    ( SELECT    A.USER_ID ,
                    B.START_DATE ,
                    D.START_DATE AS [Second Start Date] ,
                    A.FULL_NAME ,
                    A.COST_CENTER ,
                    F.DEPARTMENT_NAME ,
                    G.BU_NAME
          FROM      USERS A
                    INNER JOIN USER_PERSON B ON A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID
                    INNER JOIN TYPE_PERSON C ON C.TYPE_PERSON_ID = B.TYPE_PERSON_ID
                    INNER JOIN USER_TRANSACTION D ON D.USER_ID = A.USER_ID
                    INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONS E ON E.TRANSACTION_ID = D.TRANSACTION_ID
                    INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT F ON F.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID
                    INNER JOIN BUS_UNIT G ON G.BU_ID = D.BU_ID
                    INNER JOIN BRANCH H ON H.BRANCH_ID = D.BRANCH_ID
                    INNER JOIN POSITION J ON J.POSITION_ID = D.POSITION_ID
          WHERE     A.FLAG = 'TRUE'
        ) AS T
GROUP BY T.USER_ID
```

Comment: Well, i try it but seem error , result is loop, i have edited comment and answer.